# ELCUIApplication timeout issue

Tags: iphone, ios, android-activity, user-interaction

I am new for ios.

I have an app in which i have a login. After login user can use application.

Now i have functionality that if user have no user intraction for 2 mins than app will navigate to login screen.

I have used -

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/

For implementing it.

Everything is working fine expect when user login in the app and then use apple button so now app is in background and not uses the device for few minutes and now iphone is in lock mode.

Now if user open lock and open app, I can see a black screen,UI is not present over there.

But if i click on keyboard is shown so it is my login screen's textview but nothing is visible.

My code of main.m

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"ELCUIApplication", nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
```

When ever the timer of inactivity fires i pop the view controller to Root.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: What is the background color of ELCUIApplication?

Comment: Yes its black and i try clear color and it works. Thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the background color.

If it is black, then make it Clear color.

I had similar problem and i solved it this way.